# C# Xamarin.Forms HttpClient Occasionally Connected Scenario

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to resolve how to properly handle making an HTTP request to a REST service from a Xamarin.Forms mobile client application where the client may not be connected to a network, is possibly shutdown and restarted later where I would like to have the application complete the HTTP request when network connectivity has been re-established; basically, storing requests and retrying but also not losing the request in the case of a restart or either the application or device.

Comment: use Polly - http://www.thepollyproject.org/

Comment: I understand and have been looking at Polly but not sure how it handles storing/queuing the HTTP requests in the case of a restart.

Comment: no idea - but it's configurable enough that I assume you could add in a function to do this